InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List
In my ASP.NET 4.8 web app, the following works; I'm using PagedList for pagination:
private AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();
private IQueryable<Border> Broders;

public ViewResult Index(int? page)
{
    Broders = from s in db.Broders select s;

    if (SearchColumn == "T1")
    {
        Borders = Broders.Where(s => s.TagT1.ToString().Contains(searchString));
    }
    else if (SearchColumn == "T2")
    {
        Borders = Broders.Where(s => s.TagT2.ToString().Contains(searchString));
    }

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "status_desc":
            Borders = Borders.OrderByDescending(s => s.Status);
            break;

        case "status_desc":
            Borders = Borders.OrderByDescending(s => s.Status);
            break;

        default:
            Borders = Borders.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedOn);
            break;
    }

    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    return View(Borders.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}

I do this in an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC app using X.PagedList for pagination:
private readonly AppDbContext _context;
private IQueryable<Broder> Borders;

public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? page)
{
    var Borders = await _context.Borders.ToListAsync();

    if (SearchColumn == "T1")
    {
        Borders = (List<Initiative>)Broders.Where(s => s.TagT1.ToString().Contains(searchString));
    }
    else if (SearchColumn == "T2")
    {
        Borders = (List<Initiative>)Broders.Where(s => s.TagT2.ToString().Contains(searchString));
    }

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "status_desc":
            Borders = (List<Initiative>)Borders.OrderByDescending(s => s.Status);
            break;

        case "status_desc":
            Borders = (List<Initiative>)Borders.OrderByDescending(s => s.Status);
            break;

        default:
            Borders = (List<Initiative>)Borders.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedOn);
            break;
    }

    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    return View(Borders.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));     
}

This ASP.NET Core code throws an error

InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable2[Map.Models.Border,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Map.Models.Border]'

at line
Borders = (List<Initiative>)Borders.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedOn);

I'm new to ASP.NET Core, this is my first application. Can someone tell me what mistake I am making in my ASP.NET core method?

From this line:
var Borders = await _context.Borders.ToListAsync();

you are declaring Borders which is a List<Border> type.
Changes:

Declare the Borders as IQueryable<Border> with .AsQueryable().

Remove casting to List<Initiative> which seems unnecessary.

Don't need to create variable with global scope: private IQueryable<Broder> Borders;


public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? page)
{
    IQueryable<Broder> Borders = _context.Borders.AsQueryable();
    if (SearchColumn == "T1")
    {
        Borders = Borders.Where(s => s.TagT1.ToString().Contains(searchString));
    }
    else if (SearchColumn == "T2")
    {
        Borders = Borders.Where(s => s.TagT2.ToString().Contains(searchString));
    }
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "status_desc":
            Borders = Borders.OrderByDescending(s => s.Status);
            break;
        case "status_desc":
            Borders = Borders.OrderByDescending(s => s.Status);
            break;
        default:
            Borders = Borders.OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedOn);
            break;
    }
    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return View(Borders.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));     
}


Thanks, it worked. I see squiggle line below Index method name saying since I'm using async, I should use await operator.  Do I need to use await operator in the above method?

Hi, as the changes to resolve your compilation error, there is no use for the async/await operation. Either you can ignore the squiggle line as mentioned, or you can remove the sync and change the method signature to: public IActionResult Index(int? page)

If I remove async, then I get an error - CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult>'.

I get the above error at return statement of Index method if async removed.  There is no other code that's calling Index  method.

Check your code again, and make sure you also remove Task<>, your method signature after change should be: public IActionResult Index(int? page)

In your second code block you use var Borders = ... whcih defines a new variable of a different type (implied from the return of ToList and hides the page field. So just removing the var would be a start to get them in sync, but it may require other changes as well.
For example, you may also need to remove the ToList since a list cannot be assigned to an IQueryable variable.  It will also stop loading the entire Borders table in memory only to apply filters after that.
